# Passing multiple string values in a user entered parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm creating an SSRS and having trouble passing user entered parameter with multiple string values.

I'm having trouble with the 3rd SELECT in the example below.
How can I escape the single quote and pass multiple values in both parameters?

Thanks!!

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.#Cars (   
   Car_id int NOT NULL, 
   Color varchar(10), 
   Brand varchar(10), 
   Code int, 
) 

INSERT INTO dbo.#Cars VALUES(1, 'RED',   'Nissan',     555);
INSERT INTO dbo.#Cars VALUES(2, 'RED',   'BMW',        555);
INSERT INTO dbo.#Cars VALUES(3, 'BLUE',  'Toyota',     555);
INSERT INTO dbo.#Cars VALUES(4, 'GREEN', 'Nissan',     555);
INSERT INTO dbo.#Cars VALUES(5, 'BLACK', 'Alfa Romeo', 555);

SELECT * FROM dbo.#Cars;
SELECT * FROM dbo.#Cars WHERE Color IN ('RED', 'BLUE');

DECLARE @PARAM_COLOR VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @PARAM_BRAND VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @PARAM_COLOR =  '''RED'',''BLUE''';
SET @PARAM_BRAND = '''Nissan'',''BMW''';
SELECT * FROM dbo.#Cars WHERE Color IN (@PARAM_COLOR) AND Brand IN (@PARAM_BRAND);

DROP TABLE dbo.[#Cars]
```

Comment: There are a number of approaches to this (all of them you could search for elsewhere on SO). You could use a table variable as the parameter (instead of a comma separated list) and join to that. You could use a string split function and a join to that. You could even use dynamic SQL (though I wouldn't recommend this).

Comment: Here's an article on splitting strings if you're not fortunate enough to be running 2016 where you could make use of the string_split() function. As long as you have one of these functions built, that's a pretty easy route. If you are just messing around with stuff, you can hack together a string split function pretty easily and not care about performance. If you plan to scale this at all or put it in some kind of prod environment, it's worth your time to read the article and implement the best you can. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: Thank you everyone for your inputs!!!
I'm not there everyday, so I'll try them the next time I am there, but I can confirm our version is 2008 R2...
Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks Brien!
I'm still familiarising myself with StackOverFlow.  I've just accepted and upvoted it.

Comment: I also tried to upvote the comments from ZLK and Xedni, but they didn't allow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [table variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql) like this:

```
DECLARE @PARAM_COLOR TABLE (COLOR VARCHAR(100));
DECLARE @PARAM_BRAND TABLE (BRAND VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @PARAM_COLOR
VALUES ('RED')
    ,('BLUE')
    ,('GREEN')
    ,('BLACK');

INSERT INTO @PARAM_BRAND
VALUES ('Nissan')
    ,('BMW')
    ,('Toyota');

SELECT *
FROM dbo.#Cars
WHERE Color IN (
        SELECT COLOR
        FROM @PARAM_COLOR
        )
    AND Brand IN (
        SELECT BRAND
        FROM @PARAM_BRAND
        );
```

---

Side note: your `CREATE TABLE` has an extra comma in your example after `Code int`:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.#Cars (   
   Car_id int NOT NULL, 
   Color varchar(10), 
   Brand varchar(10), 
   Code int 
)
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your inputs!!!
I'm not there everyday, so I'll try them the next time I am there, but I can confirm our version is 2008 R2...
Thanks again!